# Execute my lambda when all the glue crawlers have run

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a requirement where I need to trigger my lambda function when all of the glue crawlers have run & my data is ready in redshift to be queried.

I have setup the following AWS cloudwatch rule but it triggers the lambda if any of the crawlers have succeeded.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Crawler State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "crawlerName": [
      "crw-raw-recon-the-hive-ces-cashflow",
      "crw-raw-recon-the-hive-ces-position",
      "crw-raw-recon-the-hive-ces-trade",
      "crw-raw-recon-the-hive-ces-movement",
      "crw-raw-recon-the-hive-ces-inventory"
    ],
    "state": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now my question is there a way I could enforce the lambda to be triggered only when all of them have succeeded?
Also, I am not sure if redshift generates any similar events when it receives data.

Comment: It looks like you are crawling the same source. Why are you using multiple crawlers instead of one? Using multiple crawlers will increase the cost associated

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Actually I am not the naming convention might make you feel that way but these are different entities.

Comment: Different JDBC sources?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes